# Number of unordered partitions of a given cardinality

Tags: combinatorics

suppose that I have N distinct elements, I would like to count the number of ways that they can be arranged in subsets of cardinality m1,m2,...,mK such that m1+m2+...+mK = N.

Example: I have N=4 elements, and I want to count the number of partitions of cardinality [2,1,1], that is
{1,2}{3}{4}
{1,3}{2}{4}
{1,4}{2}{3}
{2,3}{1}{4}
{2,4}{1}{3}
{3,4}{1}{2}
=6

Is there any general formula to compute this number? I expect something in the form P(m1,m2,...,mK).
Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To come to a result you need a slightly different setup. For a fixed cardinality of a subset it is important to know how many subsets in the arrangement have this cardinality. These subsets cannot be distinghuished on base of cardinality so we must be aware of the "danger" of multiple counting.

Let's say that $N=r_1.m_1+\cdots+r_k.m_k$ where $m_i$ corresponds with the cardinality of the subset and $r_i$ stands for the number of times that  a subset of this cardinality occurs in the partition.

E.g. $4=2.1+1.2$ corresponds with a splitup of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ in two singletons and one set of $2$ elements.

At first hand we find: $$\frac{N!}{\left(m_1!\right)^{r_1}\times\cdots\times\left(m_k!\right)^{r_k}}$$ possibilities, but this with multiple counting that must be repaired.

The endresult is:$$\frac1{r_1!\times\cdots\times r_k!}\frac{N!}{\left(m_1!\right)^{r_1}\times\cdots\times\left(m_k!\right)^{r_k}}$$

Let's return to example $4=2.1+1.2$. The first formula give $\frac{4!}{1!1!2!}=12$ possibilities. But here the possibilities $\{1\}\{2\}\{3,4\}$ and $\{2\}\{1\}\{3,4\}$ are thought of as "distinct". The second formula divides by $2$ to repair that. There are $6$ possibilities (each of them corresponds with a selection of $2$ elements out of $4$ that are "condemned" to be elements of the same subset and there are $\binom42=6$ possible selections).

Comment: Nice answer. I have just one doubt. Why only divide by 2! and not 3! ? It may also consider combinations like {3,4} {1}{2} which are same. So we should  divide by the number of partitions to eliminate redundancy right ? @drhab

Comment: @Zephyr the combination has - at first hand - been counted $2!=2$ times. Not $3!$ times. To get sight on it try it out on small numbers.

Comment: I meant suppose we have {1}{2}{3,4} then for this case, all 3! combinations of this are also considered distinct right while calculating? @drhab

Comment: @Zephyr There are $6$ combinations of that sort and in the posed question you find them all mentioned. At first hand we find $12$ because they are all counted twice.

Comment: I am sorry for bugging you. I am saying 6 combinations of that partition itself are considered distinct right ? For eg : {1}{2}{3,4} , {3,4}{1}{2} , {2}{1}{3,4} , {1}{3,4}{2} , {2}{3,4}{1} , {3,4}{2}{1}. In the calculation all these combinations are considered distinct although they are same so we should divide by 3! right instead of 2! ? @drhab

Comment: @Zephyr the order only plays a part if sets have the same cardinality hence cannot be distinghuised on base of cardinality. In the example here are 2 such sets, not 3.

Comment: yes I got that you are dividing only the ones with same cardinality. But my doubt was why are you not considering partitions with different cardinalities too when dividing because they are also redundant in the case I showed above. @drhab

Comment: @Zephyr Is your doubt still there? Take a look at example $1+2=3$. There are $\frac{3!}{1!2!}=3$ possibilities at first hand. These $\{1\}\{2,3\}$, $\{2\},\{1,3\}$ and $\{3\}\{1,2\}$. If you would be correct in your doubt then we should have a double count: $\{1\}\{2,3\}$ and $\{2,3\},\{1\}$. That then should be repaired by dividing by $2!=2$. But no, there is no such double counting and $3$ is not even divisible by $2$.

Comment: @Zephyr It was a very understandable mistake and you have grown wiser now. Go on like that.